# How to add indent in Python 3.4 interactive mode Terminator Linux?

Tags: terminal, python, indentation

I'm starting Python from basics.

The Python 3.4 Tutorial has an example for interactive mode:

```
>>> the_world_is_flat = True
>>> if the_world_is_flat:
...    print("Be careful not to fall off!")
blablabla
```

I'm on Linux, using Terminator, default Python 3.4 installation. The problem is indent before `print`. Actually, problem is any indent.

[Google](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interactive.html) says that, by default, I should have indent there with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. And I can change that with changes in `~./inputrc` file for Tab - complete (autofill) - I hope you know what I mean. So... I have different default.

My interpreter's line-editing include interactive editing (emacs commands like C-p, C-f, C-b etc. - work - YAY!) so maybe because of that, my <kbd>Tab</kbd> by default have autofill feature (YAY! I love autofill!).

Great. But if <kbd>Tab</kbd> is already occupied, how do I indent? Following the "emacs commands" track, I was trying to do it like I do in Emacs when Python file edit - 'C-c >'. But C-c (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) in shell, even when Python interpreter is on, is the interrupt keyboard shortcut, so it does not work.

If <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work and C-c > doesn't work, how do I make an indent in Python 3.4, Terminator?

I don't want to 'turn off' Tab-autofill, even if it's possible. I really like this feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took me lots of time to figure it out, but it was obvious. Instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> I just need one <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, each 4 <kbd>Space</kbd> is understood as a <kbd>Tab</kbd> in Python.

Comment: Can you provide a source reference for that? Please take our [tour] and see [answer].